# creating a single column table with a certain number pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, insert

I would like to create a table months with one column mth_id having the values 1326 to 1350 with increments of one . How do i write it with a code. Sure i can use insert 25 times but i dont want to do that >.<

months

```
mth_id
1326
1327
 .
 .
 .
1350
```

Comment: you were the guy storing month values the strange way ( now-1900 )* 12 right? So you have an oracle database at your hand and dont want to write the LOOP statement o.O?

Comment: Let's say that skynet was about to launch every nuclear missile in the world and you needed to write `sql` to loop from 1326 to 1350. What code would you write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in oracle, there is what we call `Sequences (Autonumber)`. Its syntax is

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
MINVALUE value
MAXVALUE value
START WITH value
INCREMENT BY value
CACHE value;
```

**[Read here for more details](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
 SELECT 1326 + level - 1
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 25;
```

to generate the numbers 1326 through 1350.  You can use that directly in a query (I'm assuming that is your intention based on your other questions).  Or you can use it in an `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO table_name( mth_id )
   SELECT 1326 + level - 1
     FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 25;
```